# 'Get STH over with' and 'get over with STH'

Tags: american-english, phrasal-verbs

Now I understood why I need to use 'with' when I use this phrasal verb as a meaning of 'to finish STH which is mostly the speaker does not want to do'

But I'm still confused by this thing

Why I have to put STH between the verb and particle?
Is it kind of just a rule I have to follow?

I have learned that if DO is not a pronoun I can put the DO both of between the phrasal verb or end of.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide actual sentence examples. I can think of some constructions where *with* is not required. But they might not be the same constructions that you have in mind.

Comment: I see, then there is a sentence I made as a practice. Ok. [I will get this silly thing over with] or [I will get over with this silly thing] to me both are looking same.  oh, and sorry I'm not talking should I use 'with' or not. I'm talking about the order between phrasal verb and DO